# JList in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

I have a `JList` in a `JScrollPane` and want the scroll pane to behave like it would not exists (concerning `preferredSize`) when the list contains less than 10 items. As soon as the list contains at least 10 items I want the scroll pane to have a preferred size like the list would have with 10 items. How is that possible?

Comment: I think, you want to resize `JScrollPane` according to `JList` size. If it is so, what is role of `JScrollPane`? Why not remove it?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`JList.setVisibleRowCount(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount-int-).  That will set a preferred height for the list that the scroll pane will attempt to honor.

Comment: That's quite good but not exactly what I want. If my list has less than 10 items the list is still shown that big as it is with ten items but I want no blank lines in the JScrollpane.

Comment: *"If my list has less than 10 items the list is still shown that big"*  So don't provide an `int` of ten, but however long the list is.

Comment: That's what I tried. But I don't know where to call `setVisibleRowCount`. I tried to call it in `getSize` of the `AbstractListModel`of the `JList`. But this doesn't work. Sometimes the GUI is lagging one item behind.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).